# Удаление всех элементов массива

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Имеется массив:

```
var dataSubjects = emptyArray<String>()
```

В него из базы данных добавляются элементы:

```
dataSubjects+=S
```

Как очистить этот массив перед загрузкой новых данных. Пробовал чистить массив таким способом:

```
while(i<dataSubjects.count()){
     dataSubjects[i]=""
     i++
}
```

В результате после заполнения получается такой массив:

```
"","","","Maths","Physics",...
```

А мне нужен такой:

```
"Maths","Physics",...
```

Comment: Что значит "очистить"? Массив, который нужен, не выглядит "очищенным".

Comment: @Эникейщик, Сначала массив должен очищается полностью (т.е имееть длину 0), А итоговый массив это уже после очистки и заполнения заново

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим комментатором (@Эникейщик). Вы пытаетесь в цикле просто существующим элементам массива присвоить пустую строку, при этом элементы никуда и не деваются и далее вы добавляете к существующим новые элементы. Вам нужно обнулить массив. Сами и ответили на свой вопрос - установить нулевую длину или переменной присвоить новый массив (var dataSubjects = emptyArray<String>())

Comment: @VasilBaymurzim, можно пожалуйста по подробнее, можешь рассказать как данному массиву дать длину 0, kotlin юзаю недавно и не все стандартные функции знаю)

Comment: ``dataSubjects[i]=""`` - это не очистка, а присвоение элементу массива значения "" (пустая строка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте еще раз

```
dataSubjects = emptyArray<String>();
```

Это присвоит переменной `dataSubjects` пустой массив.